# Could not add configurable product in Magent community version, shows fatal error?

Tags: magento

I'm new to magento and learning things ..

First i installed the latest magento 1.5.1.0 and it throws too many error while configuring. As it a very new version and released recently, i installed magento 1.4.2.0

Its also often throwing  some fatal errors , i dont know why its happening and almost all errors are related to products. One thing i try to add is a configurable product..

It throws **Fatal error: Call to a member function getTable() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Collection/Abstract.php on line 454**

Do anyone know how to rectify this? I tried to find answers in magento forum but failed.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself..

There was a file name configurable.php inside

**\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Mysql4\Product\Type**

and it was wrongly named something like configurable.php0343235556 and i removed the unwanted numeric characters from the extension and it all worked after that... **:)**

I already happened to found same naming problem in tierprice.php

i dont know why magento have been releasing file with this weird filenames..!!!

**Hint** on how i found the problem,

i opened the file \app\var\log\system.log and removed all its contents and tried to create a configurable product and then viewed the same file and it has the error stating 'warning :could not load file from ... '

Answer (score 1):

try to check if your database is in order with Magento Database Repair Tool http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Comment: try to rephrase this as i cant understand what you are trying to say. Also if such errors happen please make a check if your server has all the necessary to support magento installation

Comment: I tried to run the db repair tool. First it showed "Reference database connection error: #0 " So i created an empty database and refilled 'Reference Database Connection' section. After that it showed the following error 'reference DB doesn't seem to be a valid Magento database'. What should i do now?

Comment: if it shows this error then your installtion is faulty. First error probably means that your connection between code and database is failing often